# kartograph unknown shape type(25)

Tags: python-2.7, svg, shapefile, kartograph

I am trying to generate a svg map using kartograph py as below:

```
from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()
config ={"layers": {"mylayer": {"src": "42MEE250GC_SIR.shp"}} }
K.generate(config, outfile='mymap.svg')
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\k
artograph.py", line 46, in generate
    _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 48, in __init__
    me.proj = me._init_projection()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 88, in _init_projection
    map_center = self.__get_map_center()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 140, in __get_map_center
    features = self._get_bounding_geometry()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 257, in _get_bounding_geometry
    charset=layer.options['charset']
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\l
ayersource\shplayer.py", line 121, in get_features
    geom = shape2geometry(shp, ignore_holes=ignore_holes, min_area=min_area, bbo
x=bbox, proj=self.proj)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\l
ayersource\shplayer.py", line 159, in shape2geometry
    raise KartographError('unknown shape type (%d)' % shp.shapeType)
kartograph.errors.KartographError: ←[0;31;40mKartograph-Error:←[0m unknown shape
 type (25)
```

Looking at the source codes of kartograph we have this:

```
    if shp.shapeType in (5, 15):  # multi-polygon
        geom = shape2polygon(shp, ignore_holes=ignore_holes, min_area=min_area)
    elif shp.shapeType == 3:  # line
        geom = points2line(shp)
    else:
        raise KartographError('unknown shape type (%d) in shapefile %s' % (shp.shapeType, self.shpSrc))
    return geom
```

Someone can help me with this?

I tried this below and I'm getting another error.

```
if shp.shapeType == 25:
  return None
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\k
artograph.py", line 46, in generate
    _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 50, in __init__
    me.bounds_poly = me._init_bounds()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg\kartograph\m
ap.py", line 205, in _init_bounds
    raise KartographError('no features found for calculating the map bounds')
kartograph.errors.KartographError: ←[0;31;40mKartograph-Error:←[0m no features f
ound for calculating the map bounds
```

Comment: The mymap.svg is not generated

Comment: My mistake, I meant what's the input file?

Comment: The input file is a map of a Brazilian state obtained from here: ftp://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/malhas_digitais/municipio_2010/sc.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to change the source code adding this:

```
if shp.shapeType == 25:
  geom = points2line(shp)
```

I'm sure this is not the best solution but it solves my problem